# WSDL with linked xsds are not compiled dynamically using c#

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, wsdl, .net-assembly

I have a following wsdl from a WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:ProtectionToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys />
                    <sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:SignedParts>
                          <sp:Body />
                          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                        </sp:SignedParts>
                        <sp:EncryptedParts>
                          <sp:Body />
                        </sp:EncryptedParts>
                        <sp:SymmetricBinding>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:ProtectionToken>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:SpnegoContextToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                  <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys />
                                  </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:SpnegoContextToken>
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:ProtectionToken>
                            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256 />
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <sp:Layout>
                              <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict />
                              </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:Layout>
                            <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                            <sp:EncryptSignature />
                            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                        <sp:Wss11>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
                            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                            <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                            <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Wss11>
                        <sp:Trust10>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
                            <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
                            <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Trust10>
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SecureConversationToken>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:ProtectionToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256 />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
            <sp:EncryptSignature />
            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier />
            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
            <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
            <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
        <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
            <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
            <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Trust10>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing />
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetSimpleType_Input_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetSimpleType_output_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetCashFlowData_Input_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetCashFlowData_output_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
          <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <sp:Body />
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mrecserver.nj.win.com//PIData/Service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mrecserver.nj.win.com//PIData/Service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://mrecserver.nj.win.com//PIData/Service.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IService_GetSimpleType_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSimpleType" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService_GetSimpleType_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSimpleTypeResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService_GetCashFlowData_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCashFlowData" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService_GetCashFlowData_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCashFlowDataResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSimpleType">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetSimpleType" message="tns:IService_GetSimpleType_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetSimpleTypeResponse" message="tns:IService_GetSimpleType_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCashFlowData">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetCashFlowData" message="tns:IService_GetCashFlowData_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetCashFlowDataResponse" message="tns:IService_GetCashFlowData_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" type="tns:IService">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService_policy" />
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSimpleType">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetSimpleType" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService_GetSimpleType_Input_policy" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService_GetSimpleType_output_policy" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCashFlowData">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetCashFlowData" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService_GetCashFlowData_Input_policy" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IService_GetCashFlowData_output_policy" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Service">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IService">
      <soap12:address location="http://mrecserver.nj.win.com//PIData/Service.svc" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>http://mrecserver.nj.win.com//PIData/Service.svc</wsa10:Address>
        <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
          <Dns>localhost</Dns>
        </Identity>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

..and the following code to return a compiled assembly to use to save the methods.

```
/// <summary>
/// Compiles an assembly from the proxy class provided by the ServiceDescriptionImporter.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="descriptionImporter"></param>
/// <returns>An assembly that can be used to execute the web service methods.</returns>
private Assembly CompileAssembly(ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter)
{
    // a namespace and compile unit are needed by importer
    CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace();
    CodeCompileUnit codeUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();

    codeUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace);

    ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings importWarnings = descriptionImporter.Import(codeNamespace, codeUnit);

    if (importWarnings == 0) // no warnings
    {
        // create a c# compiler
        CodeDomProvider compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        // include the assembly references needed to compile
        string[] references = new string[2] { "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll" };

        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(references);

        // compile into assembly
        CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, codeUnit);

        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
        {
            // trap these errors and make them available to exception object
            throw new Exception("Compilation Error Creating Assembly");
        }

        // all done....
        return results.CompiledAssembly;
    }
    else
    {
        // warnings issued from importers, something wrong with WSDL
        throw new Exception("Invalid WSDL");
    }
}
```

The wsdl passed always go to else part and throw an exception "Invalid WSDL". I noticed that the same piece of code works for those wsdl that doesn't have any linked xsd (i.e. xsd0, xsd1 or xsd2). Can anyone think what could be the problem? and, why does some wcf services have linked xsds and some don't?

Here I am trying to read the wsdl to get all the methods and the properties. I know we can do this easily by adding service reference but I want to do this dynammically as user will pass the service url and I will generate the list of methods with properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that the ServiceDescriptionImporter that is used to generate proxies for the old Xml Web Services (ASMX) assumed it is given a "flattened" wsdl document. That means all the service description documents are in a single wsdl document. You'll need to add a behavior to the WCF service you're targeting to generate the flatten wsdl for your code to work. There are several article on how to generate flattened wsdl but this [one](http://delriodanny.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-generate-single-file-wsdl-ie.html) should get you started.

EDIT(to summerize comments chat): If you don't have control over the WCF service and still want to use this technique for dynamically generating proxies then you'll need to write code that parses the wsdl to replace the xsd:import elements with the XSD documents pointed to by the url in the import element. The HttpWebRequest .NET Framework class can be used to get the wsdl from a service by calling the service metadata endpoint as if it were a "web page".

Parse the wsdl using your favorite XML class (either XmlDocument or XDocument) to find the import elements and callout for the XSD "web pages" with value in the schemaLocation attribute. You shouldn't need to make any changes in the XSD XML except to remove the XML directive that will be included in the "page" contents. Finally, feed the flattened wsdl to the ServiceDescriptionImporter.

Comment: Thanks for great pointer. I was able to create a simple test application from the blog and generate one single wsdl. tomorrow I will try my actual code (as metioned in original post) if it works :) But really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sixto, was just thinking how the approach in the link will work at runtime? I mean, i just pass the service url and my code append "?wsdl" and do compilation and rest. Not sure how can i dynamically do all that what they did in the code that required changes in web.config of the service. Any pointer on that would really help.

Comment: Changing your WCF service web.config file to add the wsdl flattening behavior is only done once. After this change, the service will always send out the flattened wsdl. Your client code should not need to change at all. The ServiceDescriptionImporter will just consume the wsdl it receives from the WCF service as it does with an ASMX based web service.

Comment: Sixto, you are right that no need to change anything in client but issue is I can't change anything in service side. My client code receives just a service url (third party) and I try to read the wsdl and generate methods/properties. So I can't change the WCF service config file or anything. I need a way to read that service url and inject the code to flatten the wsdl before it is consumed by the client code. Sound reasonable?

Comment: Yup, wsdl in the end is just XML. You'll need to write code that parses the wsdl to replace the xsd:import elements with the XSD documents pointed to by the url in the import element. Search for HttpWebRequest and c# to find articles on how to use it to get a web page's contents which for you will be the wsdl "web page". Next use either XmlDocument or XDocument to find the import elements and callout for the XSD "web pages" from the found links. Finally, feed the flattened wsdl to your current code.

Comment: hmm, I thought of using "flatten wsdl" from above link somehow. Seems I need to create my own wsdl parser to read XSDs. Is it as simple as find and replace the <xsd:import> tags with <xs:schema> tags from corresponding xsd documents? or there is some massaging required on xsd document content before putting it in the wsdl file?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create the wsdl parser. You shouldn't need to make any changes in the XSD XML except to remove the XML directive that will be included in the "page" contents.

Comment: great sixto! I will try that and will confirm the success :) Also, if you can edit your answer by adding this solution. I can accept it as correct answer and give full credit to you!!