# How to read Web Method and parameters name from Web Service

Tags: c#

I am C#.NET developer. I am writing a application which can call web service dynamically. I got one web service that is written in Java. This web service returns only web method name in WSDL file but doesn't returns their input/output parameters details. They keep all details in another XSD link. That xsd link present in WSDL file. I want to know that how I can read that XSD file and how we can read Web Method name and their input and output parameters.

I am looking help on priority.

this is sample link: http://www.java-tutorial.ch/api-doc/ArticleService.html#src.N10068

Thanks in advance.
Rajeev

Comment: Why not import the WSDL as a service reference in VS, or using svcutil.exe (WCF), or wsdl.exe?

Comment: How exactly are you "dynamically" invoking those web services? Some possibly related threads [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550077/dynamically-invoke-a-web-service-at-runtime), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550077/dynamically-invoke-a-web-service-at-runtime) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492394/wsdl-with-linked-xsds-are-not-compiled-dynamically-using-c-sharp)

Comment: did you look at [WsdlImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have just service url like "http://192.168.11.100:9080/AbcWebServices/MyAPICustomer?wsdl". I have to read all methods and parameters (input/output) name of each methods in run time and invoke each methods with some predefined value. As I mentioned that I can find only method name when I call web service. There is another link ("http://192.168.11.100:9080/WS/ArticleService?xsd=2") inside result xml which returns all parameter of each method. I am not sure how to find and invoke inside link to get all parameter name of each service. I am writing generic application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio and are looking to generate proxy classes to consume the web service you need to add a web reference to the WSDL. You can find instructions on how to do this [at microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

This process will generate the classes required to interact with the webservice, including all the methods and properties.

This isn't the only way to generate the proxy classes, but IMHO it's the easiest.

Here is a working example of what you can end up with:

I develop against an ERP system called Netsuite. They provide a WSDL at https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2013_2_0/netsuite.wsdl.

Following the instructions in the link above I show the following:

[image: Netsuite Web reference]

I can now call the class like any other. In order to view the classes now available, 
view the reference in the Object Browser. The image below shows all the classes, each one of course you can click into to see what properties are available.

[image: partial class list]

Answer (score 0):

XSD files are valid XML which means you can parse it with classes from the System.Xml or System.Xml.Linq namespaces. I'm assuming when you say you're dynamically calling the web service that you can't rely on a static WSDL reference in Visual Studio

Comment: I have just service url like "192.168.11.100:9080/AbcWebServices/MyAPICustomer?wsdl";. I have to read all methods and parameters (input/output) name of each methods in run time and invoke each methods with some predefined value. As I mentioned that I can find only method name when I call web service. There is another link ("192.168.11.100:9080/WS/ArticleService?xsd=2") inside result xml which returns all parameter of each method. I am not sure how to find and invoke inside link to get all parameter name of each service. I am writing generic application.

Comment: Should be the same way you issue any other web request